# How to align ul# menu horizontally with page

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles centering (horizontally) my ul# menu with the middle of the page. It is all functioning properly and as intended, I am just having issues with the centering.

Here is the CSS:

```
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 15px;
}

ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 46px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 150px;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    background-color:grey;
    opacity:1;
    height:20px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#30F;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menucontainer {
    position:absolute; 
    width:700px;
    top:158px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity:0.8; 
    z-index:20;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://games.engagearcade.com">Games</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="http://descent.engagearcade.com">>> Descent</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://prizes.engagearcade.com">Prizes</a>
</li>

<li>
     <a href="http://ladder.engagearcade.com">Ladder</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://community.engagearcade.com">Community</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="http://community.engagearcade.com">>> Submissions</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="http://support.engagearcade.com">>> Support/Help</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://forums.engagearcade.com">Forums</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://about.engagearcade.com">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="http://about.engagearcade.com">>> Engage Arcade</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="http://involved.engagearcade.com">>> Those Involved</a>
       </li>

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Sorry for the big hunk of code, but I do not know exactly which parts would be relevant in helping solve the issue. The main thing to look for is the menucontainer.

Cheers for any suggestions.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HcfMT/

Comment: Maybe a fiddle would be great?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HcfMT/ I'll chuck it in the question also. As you see it is sticks to the left of the page rather than in the center, which I believe the margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; from the menucontainer should do.

Comment: try `text-align: center;` to `#menucontainer`: http://jsfiddle.net/MC2AT/

Comment: _“which I believe the margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; from the menucontainer should do”_ – which of course they _don’t_, because you positioned the container absolutely …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's positioned absolutely. Get rid of that, since you're misusing it anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/HcfMT/2/

```
width:700px;
margin-top:158px;
```

Comment: Oh! I can't believe I missed that. I started off wanting it to be positioned 15px from the right, and later decided instead to center it instead and left it positioned absolutely. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix... you are very close to having it.

```
#menucontainer
    position:absolute; 
    width:700px;
    top:158px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity:0.8; 
    z-index:20;
```

to

```
#menucontainer {
    position:relative; 
    width:700px;
    top:158px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity:0.8; 
    z-index:20;
}
```

You need the #menucontainer to be relatively positioned.